# What are different ways to read unstructured data from .pdf or .tiff

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, pdf, ocr

We had build a software for US mortgage industry which design to give or produce qualifying income to particular loan applicant.

Client can upload `.pdf` or `.tiff` and then we have [abbyy](https://support.abbyy.com/hc/en-us/) who can able to read and transform data in `SQL`. If client uploaded any paystub then we had created templates (almost 800 now) to map specific format of paystub (as there are many paystub format are available in US) with help of **abbyy**

Now we want to remove this template dependencies, So is there any way where we can read unstructured data without creating mapper like templates.

Comment: This is a non-trivial task. And there is quite expensive (for a reason) software, that does just that. I've been working with Kofax but I am sure, there are others, too. If you really want to write it yourself, prepare for several man-years of development. The OCR is the easy part, btw.

Comment: ^-- (not affiliated to Kofax)

Comment: Indeed, just like @Fildor says, OCR is the easy part. *Removing template dependencies* implies implementing a certain degree of intelligence that can recognize labels and values and *correlate them*. This can be quite a task, in particular as there are numerous forms out there for which even humans (at least ones who have not yet dealt with those very forms) have problems identifying the relations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what these templates are (maybe screenshots). Is the template mapping based on text extraction+position (e.g. adjacent strings are key+value)? Or just based on a rectangular area (e.g. first name is in area X?)

Comment: I am not able to upload any screenshots. But what your saying is some what right. By using specific keys abbyy can able to identify particular form e.g 1040 document can be identified by giving keys like SSN, first borrower name etc. and by applying coordination we need draw [abbyy is having a tool to do that] all fields to design a template for 1040.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, ABBYY OCR does have the "default template" for invoices. You may discard all of your customization features and go drop your 800+ templates.

The purpose of this action is not clear, but indeed you can do that and your invoices will be recognized still.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are looking same solution for pay-stub also. When you say invoices does it mean all semi structure documents?Does ABBYY have default template for paystubs also?

Comment: ABBYY only has default templates for invoices.
You may also hire a good FlexiLayout developer to turn your 800+ bad templates into 1 good.

Comment: we have created 800+ templates because we have that many paystubs documents. So these are not bad templates as such but when you say 800+ templates into 1 templates are you suggesting of having 1 generic template?

Comment: Having 800+ manually developed templates indeed means they are not good templates. Whenever a number of templates for 1 document exceeds 10, you should have considered developing a generic template.